# Как обернуть много методов?

Tags: c#

Задача следующая.
Есть некий обособленный класс Test с методом TestMethod.

```
public Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

Также есть множество других классов, которые наследуются от одного абстрактного класса и в этих классах большое количество методов. 
Нужно, чтобы во всех этих методах сначала вызывался TestMethod(), затем шло непосредственно тело самого метода и затем снова вызывался TestMethod(), то есть:

```
public Class1:AbstractClass
{
    public void Method1()
    {
         TestMethod()
         //тело метода
         TestMethod()
    }
    public void Method2()
    {
         TestMethod()
         //тело метода
         TestMethod()
    }

}
```

Понятное дело, что можно так и прописать в каждом методе каждого класса. Но может есть более изящный способ обернуть тела методов?

**(!!!)** Методы могут иметь разные входные и выходные параметры. Не только void и без параметров.

Comment: Да, методы могут иметь разные входные и выходные параметры.

Comment: Это задача для AOP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать какой-нибудь AOP-фреймворк. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/633710/276994) есть большой их список.

Давайте сделаем пример с популярным [Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/).

Отмечу сразу, нам нужно будет модифицировать код. Перехватываемые методы (то есть, те методы, к которым мы «добавляем» вызов `TestMethod`) должны быть виртуальными. Если это — слишком большое ограничение, вам понадобится другой AOP-фреймворк (например, [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)).

Пусть наш код такой:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var derived = new Derived();
        derived.M3();
    }
}

class Base
{
    public void M1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base::M1");
    }

    public int M2(int arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Base::M2, arg = {arg}");
        return arg + 1;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public int M3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived::M3");
        return M2(10);
    }
}
```

и тестовый класс

```
class Test
{
    public static void TestMethod(bool entry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test::TestMethod ({(entry ? "in" : "out")})");
    }
}
```

Подключим через nuget [Castle.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core), и допишем наш интерсептор:

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;

public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Test.TestMethod();
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        finally
        {
            Test.TestMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Затем (ограничение Castle.Proxy) нам нужно сделать наши классы публичными, а методы виртуальными. Получаем такой изменённый код:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void M1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base::M1");
    }

    public virtual int M2(int arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Base::M2, arg = {arg}");
        return arg + 1;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public virtual int M3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived::M3");
        return M2(10);
    }
}
```

Меняем `Main`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = new Interceptor();
        var proxy = new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxy<Derived>(i);
        proxy.M3();
    }
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
Test::TestMethod (in)
Derived::M3
Test::TestMethod (in)
Base::M2, arg = 10
Test::TestMethod (out)
Test::TestMethod (out)
```

Comment: Кошмар ... Откуда все это можно знать.... Это же надо когда-нибудь столкнуться с этим ...

Comment: @MaximK: Угу, за время работы приходилось сталкиваться со всяким.

Answer (score 4):

Как насчёт using? Хотя это и не очень-то корректно семантически:

```
public void Method1(){
    using (new TestMethodWrapper()){
        //тело метода
    }
}

public class TestMethodWrapper : IDisposable {
    public TestMethodWrapper(){
        TestMethod();
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        TestMethod();
    }
}
```