# Как написать метод, который будет выполняться перед каждым другим методом?

Tags: c#

Есть метод A и методы B,С,D,E.
Нужно метод A выполнить перед каждым методом B,С,D,E, когда они будут запускаться и если метод A будет false, то выйти и не выполнять следующий код.
Фактически нужно вписать выполнение метода А в каждый из методов.
Но есть ли какой-то лучшей способ обёртки, что б не прописывать одинаковые действия в каждом из методов и наследовать класс А (с методом А) и пропускать всё через него?

Comment: B,C,D,E - независимы друг от друга?

Comment: @Grundy совершенно разные. Но метод А "проверочный" и если он не сработает, то их не выполнять

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582799/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Нет смысла тянуть AOP или писать декораторы ради 4 методов. Просто впишите проверку в код и забудьте.

Comment: Атрибуты сами по себе ничего не делают, это просто объекты, «навешенные» на ваш объект, наподобие ценников.

Comment: Точно так же при наследовании новые методы автоматически ничего не делают. C# — язык без магии. Вы наверняка имеете в виду какой-нибудь AOP-фреймворк.

Comment: Уточните технологию. WPF, WebForms, WinForms, ASP.NET and etc...

Comment: Можно сделать что-то типа `class SecretObjectWrapper { public SecretObject Instance { get { проверка и выбрасывание исключения; return instance; } } }` И обращаться к `SecretObject` только через `SecretObjectWrapper.Instance`: `SecretObjectWrapper.Instance.Method1();` Правда, всегда можно `SecretObjectWrapper.Instance` сохранить в переменную и использовать ее, но это уже на вашей совести

Comment: @VladD через ремоутинг прокси можно сделать, с определенными ограничениями. но атрибуты тут да, ни при чем.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool A()
{
    bool result = false;
    // действия
    return result; // если тут вернёт false, ваши методы будут прекращать работу
}

void B()
{
    if (!A()) return;
    // Действия
}
```

Аналогично, как в B(), будет и в других методах (C-E)

Также есть вариант с использованием делегатов

```
delegate bool MyDelegate;
public Main()
{
    MyDelegate = A;
}

bool A()
{
    bool result = false;
    // действия
    return result; // если тут вернёт false, ваши методы будут прекращать работу
}

void B()
{
    if (!MyDelegate.Invoke()) return;
    // Действия
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool Проверка()
{
    return true; // вернуть false если что-то не так
}

void ОбычныйМетод()
{
    if (!Проверка()) return;
    // какие-то действия
}
```